# Basic query about python loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

So , I have this code snippet :

```
import sys

while True:
  print("Make sure the number of digits are exactly 12 : ")
  x = input()
  if str(x) == 12:
      break

  code = []

  for i in range(12):
      code[i] = int(x[i])
```

I want the program to repeat the lines , "Make sure .... 12 :" if 12 digits are not inputed. After that , I am copying them to an array to access each individual element of it to do very basic arithmetic calculations . Am I going in the right direction ? I am totally new to python , how can I fix this ? The above code is showing the following error .

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arjo\Desktop\hw2a.py", line 14, in <module>
    code[i] = int(x[i])
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IndexError: list assignment index out of range` is occuring because you have an empty list and are trying to *update* the first element. Since the list is empty there is no first element, so the exception is raised.

One way to correct this problem is to use `code.append(x[i])` but there is an easier way in this case. The default `list` constructor will do exactly what you want

I think you probably want something like this

```
while True:
  print("Make sure the number of digits are exactly 12 : ")
  x = input()
  if len(x) != 12:   # if the length is not 12
      continue       # ask again

  code = list(x)
```

This will keep asking for more input until exactly 12 characters are entered

Comment: so i won't need to use the for loop part at all then ? , how should I access the individual elements in code array ? . Also , we can skip this line then code = [] ?

Comment: @novice7, you don't need the `code = []` line. You access the elements as you were `code[i]` where i is bewteen 0 and 11

Answer (score 3):

You're not creating an array of inputs with `x`, but rather overwriting it each time.  Your comparison is also wrong; you don't want to see that the string of `x` *is*, 12, but that it has a length of 12:

```
x = []
while True:
  print("Make sure the number of digits are exactly 12 : ")
  x.append(input())
  if len(x) == 12:
      break
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to `break` when the length of `x` is `12`?

Comment: @gnibbler I think so .. why?

Comment: The way the code is indented now, all of the stuff about `code` will be skipped

Comment: @gnibbler true, I didn't consider that; it should probably be dedented then

Comment: Depends on the intent of the while loop. If there is supposed to be just one input processed the part under the break should be dedented.

Answer (score 0):

No, this doesn't look like it will work... Try changing this:

```
if str(x) == 12:
      break
```

into this:

```
if len(str(x)) == 12: 
    break
```

Hope that helps...